# Railsでデータタイプを間違えて作業を進めてしまった場合

Tags: ruby-on-rails

とあるテーブルのカラム型を「text」とするところ間違えて「body」としてしまいました。

時すでに遅しで、そのまま気づかずに、その後もモデルを作ったりしてしまいました。

ここで、型を変更もしくは、一旦削除したいのですが、エラーがでます。

状況：

```
 up     20160623115522  Rename comment column to best answer
 up     20160623120025  Rename note column to best answer
 up     20160627113038  Add body to best answer 
 up     20160705091749  Add thx to best answer #間違えてる箇所
 up     20160710104044  Add name to best answer
```

対処：rails generate migration RemoveThxFromBestAnswerとしたりrails g migration change_datatype_thx_of_best_answerとして、 rake db:migrateしたのですが、

```
 == 20160712071004 RemoveThxFromBestAnswer: migrating ==========================
 -- remove_column(:best_answers, :thx, :body)
 rake aborted!
 StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

 undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
 Did you mean?  to_s

 #間違えた時に作ったmigrateファイル
 20160705091749  Add thx to best answer
 class AddThxToBestAnswer < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     add_column :best_answers, :thx, :body
   end
 end

 #適用させようと失敗するmigrateファイル
 class RemoveThxFromBestAnswer < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     remove_column :best_answers, :thx, :body
   end
 end
```

と、でて受け付けてもらえません。
どうすればいいでしょうか？ご教授お願いします。

Comment: エラーが出ているマイグレーションファイルのソースコードがないと答えづらそうです。追加してもらえないでしょうか?

Comment: migrateファイルを追記しました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

開発の途中であって、面倒をみるべき運用中の DB がないのであるならば、ミスった migration ファイルを直接書き換えて、 `rake db:migrate:reset` するのが一番早いです。 今現在の migration ファイル(たち) でもって、 1 からデータベースを作りなおします。